# Spring MVC4 Session Management

Tags: spring, jsp, session

I am developing a small spring project in which the login page has two type of users admin and staff. on login attempt i want to apply session using spring MVC4 and also wants to open jsp based on the user role(Admin or Staff).
the session has four/five fields like name,id,role,SessionId. i want these information to travel through the jsp pages. But i don't want to do this using url parameter passing.

I don't know how to do this because i am new in spring and this is my first project. Help me Please.
If someone can provide me the sample code and guide me on this then it would be very helpfull.

// Login.jsp code

```
var MobileNo=$('#mobno').val();
            var StaffPwd=$('#pwd').val();
            $.ajax
            (
                    {
                    url: "http://localhost:8080/OnlineStore/kmsg/grocery/Login",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {MobileNo: MobileNo,StaffPwd: StaffPwd},
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        var vUserRole = data["UserRole"];
                        var vUserName = data["UserName"];

                        if(data==="")
                            {
                            alert("Login Failed");
                            }
                        else
                            {
                            if(vUserRole == "Admin")
                                {
                                   alert("Login Success: " + vUserName);
                                   window.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/OnlineStore/JspPages/City.jsp";
                                }
                            if(vUserRole == "CityAdmin")
                                {
                                    alert("Login Success: " + vUserName);
                                     window.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/OnlineStore/JspPages/Locality.jsp";
                                }
                            if(vUserRole == "Staff")
                                {
                                    alert("Login Success: " + vUserName);
                                    window.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/OnlineStore/JspPages/CustomerOrder.jsp";
                                }                           
                            }
                    },
                    error: function(e)
                    {
                    alert('Error:' +e)
                    }
                    }
            );
```

// this is controller code

```
 @RequestMapping("/Login") 
public @ResponseBody UserServiceModel selectStaff(@RequestParam Map<String,String> requestParams) throws Exception 
{ 
String MobileNo = requestParams.get("MobileNo"); 
String StaffPwd = requestParams.get("StaffPwd"); 
return staffAdapter.login(MobileNo, StaffPwd); 
}

--------------
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just store your data in some serializable object. For e.g.:

```
public class SessionData implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String id;
    private String role;

    //etc..

}
```

then set this object as the session attribute when the user first logs in:

```
session.setAttribute("sessionData", new SessionData(name, id, role, etc...))
```

To access this object in a JSP page you can use: `${sessionScope['sessionData']}`, to access a specific field:

```
${sessionScope['sessionData'].id}
${sessionScope['sessionData'].name}
${sessionScope['sessionData'].role}
```

To access these attributes in JavaScript files just define some page data in your JSP page, for e.g.:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    pageData = {
        id: "${sessionScope['sessionData'].id}",
        name: "${sessionScope['sessionData'].name}",
        role: "${sessionScope['sessionData'].role}"
    }
</script>
```

and in js file reference them via:

```
pageData.id
pageData.name
pageData.role
```

I can see that you trying to create roles based application. You are already using Spring MVC, any reason why not use [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/) along with it? I would highly advice doing so as it will make your life much easier.

Comment: Paulius, How can i implement the same using Spring Security. i have no idea. can u guide me on this ?